# When are nested sequences numbered in the Symfony YAML Component

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I'm using the Symfony YAML Component to parse Flexget config files. However there are times when it converts the sequence of TV Shows to a numbered list when it actually should be a list with dashes `-`.

WRONG example:

```
templates:
  tv:
    private_torrents: no
    regexp:
      accept:
        12: 'Absolute Duo'
        13: 'Yuri Kuma Arashi'
        14: 'Miritari!'
        ...
```

Correct example:

```
templates:
  tv:
    private_torrents: no
    regexp:
      accept:
        - 'Absolute Duo'
        - 'Yuri Kuma Arashi'
        - 'Miritari!'
        ...
```

How do I prevent this from happening?

This is how I dump my YAML to file:
`$config = Yaml::dump($this->config, 99, 2);`

I use `99` because I never want inline config.

The config I'm dumping:

```
array (size=2)
  'templates' => 
    array (size=1)
      'tv' => 
        array (size=4)
          'private_torrents' => string 'no' (length=2)
          'regexp' => 
            array (size=1)
              'accept' => 
                array (size=9)
                  0 => string 'Shingeki no Bahamut' (length=19)
                  1 => string 'Sora no Method' (length=14)
                  2 => string 'Gugure! Kokkuri-san' (length=19)
                  3 => string 'Majin Bone' (length=10)
                  4 => string 'Grisaia no Kajitsu' (length=18)
                  5 => string 'Queen's Blade Rurou no Senshi' (length=29)
                  6 => string 'Daitoshokan no Hitsujikai' (length=25)
                  7 => string 'Trinity Seven' (length=13)
                  8 => string 'Akame ga Kill!' (length=14)
```

Comment: Can you show what the array looks like that you are dumping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you mine posting the config input you are dumping ?

also, the only reason I guess the problem could be, is that your input is considered as a hash, looking at this line shows that if your array does not contain keys from 0 to count-1, your input will be considered as hash:

https://github.com/symfony/Yaml/blob/master/Dumper.php#L57

And if considered as a hash, instead of outputting `"-"`, it will output `"key: value"` yaml

https://github.com/symfony/Yaml/blob/master/Dumper.php#L64

Comment: updated my question! However I'm still at loss, in what way will my array not contain the proper keys? How can that happen? Does that happen when I unset a key and then dumping it without resetting all the keys?

Comment: i will test your config later. however i see it contains all 9 keys

Comment: in the meantime you can maybe create a branch in yr yaml dep and remove this logic to see if it comes from there

Comment: Yup it's the key's fault. If I reset the keys there's no problem and the dashes list is maintained :)